# eof from string, not a stream

Tags: c++, string, eof

I have a secret "mission" to write Vigenère cipher with it's analysis with ascii alphabet.

I have some troubles with encrypting text.

There are two kinds of them:

1) If I use whole ascii table, there are some troubles with decrypting text, because i use "system" chars that kills my text (by the way, it is "War and Peace" written by Tolstoy). Should i use it truncated version?
if yes, so - could i do operations from next question with truncated ascii table?

2) I want to have whole my text in one string. I can do it by this:

```
string s;
string p = "";
ifstream in("text_for_encryption.txt");
while (getline(in, s))
{
 p+=s;
 p+="\n";
}
```

"s" is the temporary string, and "p" is the string that has all text from file in it (with endl's and, of course, EOF)
i will make a cycle for "p" which looks like as

```
while (not eof in p)
{
  take first keyword.length() chars from "p"? check every of them for EOF and encrypt them. (they will be deleted from p)
  kick them in file "encrypted_text.txt"
}
```

in pseudocode (yeah, it is shit-like :( ).

so, the question is - how can i compare a string element with eof?
maybe, i can't google good, but i couldn't find the answer for this question.

Thanks in advance for every advice!

---

Update:
if i will encrypt string-by-string, it wll be easy to get a length of a key by Fridman's method (if the key is quite small).
so i want to encrypt text with endl's for more security

Comment: Why don't you encrypt each line as you go?

Comment: Why check for EOF?  Just encrypt the whole string, you know its length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For encrypting, it depends largely on what you want to encrypt,
and what you want to do with the encrypted text.  The usual 
solution is to encrypt the bytes values (not the characters);
this means that you'll have to read and write the encrypted file
in binary mode, but since it's not meant to be readable anyway,
that's usually not an issue.

For the rest, strings do not have "EOF" characters.  In fact,
there is no such thing as an EOF character[1].  (Nor en `endl`
character, either.)  EOF is, in fact, an "event" which occurs
when reading from a stream; in C++, it is, in fact, treated as
a sort of an error.  `std::istream` functions which can return
EOF (e.g. `std::istream::get()`) return `int`, and not `char`,
in order to be able to return an out of band value.

Strings do have a known length.  To visit all of the characters
in a string:

```
for ( std::string::const_iterator current = s.begin();
        current != s.end();
        ++ current ) {
    //  Do something with *current...
}
```

(If you have C++11, you can replace
`std::string::const_iterator` with `auto`.  This is much simpler
to type, but until you master the iterator idioms, it's probably
better to write the type out, to ensure you understand what is
going on.)

[1] Historically, text files have had EOF characters on some
systems.  This is *not* the end of file that you see with
`std::istream::get()`, but even today, if you open a file in
text mode under Windows, a 0x1A in the file will trigger the end
of file event in the input.